# Django error: relation "users_user" does not exist

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the following error during migration:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "users_user" does not exist

```
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/api/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/api/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/api/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/api/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from ..managers.user import UserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # Email identifier, primary key, unique identifier for the user.
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        app_label = "users"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        """
        Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`
        """
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
```

Settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

Anything I have missed?

Comment: Have you done `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @tgdn Yep so I did ``makemigrations`` which works with no errors, then on doing ``migrate`` I get the above error.

Comment: Are you trying to have a `CUSTOM_USER_MODEL` ?

Comment: I'm using ``AUTH_USER_MODEL``

Comment: Try to rename your model.

Comment: Is it the first time you migrate? As it should be 

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

Comment: @tgdn first time I have migrated yes

Comment: Inside your user app, you should have a folder `migrations`. It should only contain `0001_initial.py` and `__init__.py`. Is that correct?

Try running `./manage.py sqlmigrate user 0001_initial` and see what it does, because thats where the error comes from

Comment: @tgdn ok I resolved this by removing other apps first and running migrations first on the main user model. thanks for your help. I'm happy to accept your answer if you post one.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Inside your user app, you should have a folder `migrations`. It should only contain `0001_initial.py` and `__init__.py`. Is that correct?

Try running `./manage.py sqlmigrate user 0001_initial` and see what it does, because thats where the error comes from

Comment: This was my issue - I had never run the actual initial User migration. 

You might have not run `python manage.py makemigrations appname`yet  - once you do that and `migrate` after, everything should be fine.

Comment: Running first ./manage.py migrate user 0001_initial worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Another issue can also be the fact that you were using the database for another application. So if this can be the case just drop the database before making migrations again

Comment: I literally sqlflushed my db then dropped it and recreated another one with the same properties and then `./manage.py migrate` worked
none of the above answers helped

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered with the same issue in Postgres DB.

Steps to follow:

- remove previous db and create new one
- add **migration** folder and add ****init**.py** empty file inside migration folder of each app having models
- now use command `python manage.py makemigrations`
- use command `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, and what I did was to run `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` and do not forget to add `<app_name>` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file