# relation does not exist(postgresql, django)

Tags: django

I'm using django with postgresql. But when I run the app, I get the following error:

> relation "django_session" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se...

I searched for this error, but the only situation people talked about was when the name of the table had mixed case characters. But the table name in my case is all in small letters so this shouldn't happen. What is wrong here?
Thanks

p.s.
This is the project I'm working with.
https://github.com/mirumee/saleor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django error: relation "users\_user" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672190/django-error-relation-users-user-does-not-exist)

Comment: Have you tried `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Oh... Of course... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just execute the migrate command:

docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate

Then create superuser:

docker-compose exec web python manage.py createsuperuser

And enter in the new superuser log in.